# Uniform digit generator

Tags: probability, expectation

The question goes as follows:

> Let there be a random digit generator, generating the numbers $0,1,2,...,9$ uniformly and independently. The generator writes the numbers from left to right.
>
> a) What is the expected value for the number of **different** digits appearing between two zeroes?
>
> b) What is the distribution of the number of times the number $0$ appeared between two appearances of $9$?
>
> c) Assuming the first digit is 8. What is the expected value of the number made up from the first four digits?

Well, 'c' was pretty simple, and is just $8000 + 4.5*100 + 4.5*10 + 4.5*1 = 8499.5$, since the expectation of the digit generated is $4.5$ and they are independent.

I had problems with solving 'a' and 'b', and would be happy to see both rigorous approach and simple approach if there are.

Thanks.

Comment: For (a), you are equally likely to see a $9$ or a $0$ first after your first $0$, so you expect to see $0.5$ $9$s before your next $0$. This is true for all of the other digits too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a, the probability that a $1$ comes up between two zeros is $\frac 12$ because it just comes down to which comes first, the next $1$ or the next $0$.  Make an indicator variable of the fact that a $1$ is there.  Its expected value is $\frac 12$.  By linearity of expectation, the expected number of different digits between two zeros is $9 \cdot \frac 12=4.5$

For b, the chance we have no zeros is $\frac 12$ because a $9$ has to come before the next zero.  Once that $0$ comes, it is again $\frac 12$ that the next $0$ comes before the next $9$, so the chance of $n$ zeros is $\frac 1{2^{n+1}}$

Answer (score 1):

One rigorous solution for b) can be this:

Let $d$ be the number of (not necessarily distinct) digits betweens two appearances of number 9, and $x$ the number of zeroes that appear in these digits, then $$P(x=k|d) = \frac{{d \choose k} 8^{d-k}}{9^d}$$ because that's the number of ways you can accomodate $k$ zeroes and $d-k$ other digits (distinct from zero or nine) in $d$ slots, and the universe has $9^d$ posibilities (any digit distinct from 9 in any of the $d$ places).

Since $d$ can be viewed as the number of trials you have to do before getting another 9, $d$ follows a geometric distribution with $p = \frac{1}{10}$ $$P(d) = (\frac{9}{10})^d \frac{1}{10}$$

Now, by the law of total probability

$$P(x = k) = \sum_{d=k}^{\infty} P(x=k|d) P(d) = \sum_{d=k}^{\infty} \frac{{d \choose k} 8^{d-k}}{9^d} (\frac{9}{10})^d \frac{1}{10}$$

If you opperate this equation using $u = d-k$ instead of $d$, you get

$$P(x = k) =\frac{1}{10^{k+1}} \sum_{u=0}^{\infty} {{u+k} \choose k} (\frac{4}{5})^{u} = \frac{5^{k+1}}{10^{k+1}} = \frac{1}{2^{k+1}}$$